# How can I make one output to become others input?

Tags: function, call

I have two m files named encoder and decoder.Now I want to make one more m files called main function that can run automatically.Before this I have to insert the input at encoder.m,run it and insert the output of encoder.m at decoder.m manually.So, how can I make it so that I can just insert the input and get the output of decoder.m?

Comment: Could you post some code..

Answer (score 0):

since you havent posted any of your work ,
try using the pipe option in this case.Hope this helps
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html

Comment: Yes.I want to insert the output of encoder to become the input of decoder.